# Open source/free .fla file editor?

Tags: windows, linux, open-source, swf, adobe-flash

Is there any free software to edit .fla file?

Platform: Linux or Windows will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only one I know of is [FlashDevelop](http://osflash.org/flashdevelop).

In addition, possibly take a look at trials/demos of official Flash and/or other Flash editing tools.

Comment: FlashDevelop can not edit FLA files